Fractional part of sequence $x^m$
Let the sequence $a_m = x^m-\lfloor{x^m}\rfloor$, where m is a nonnegative integer and x is a real number, with $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ representing the greatest integer less than or equal to x. Show that if $a_m$ eventually exhibits cyclic behavior, then x must be an integer?
I'm having difficulty with this problem. I've been trying to prove it by contradiction, which means showing that the sequence is not cyclic if $x$ is not an integer. I'm currently stuck on the part where $x$ can be expressed as $k+l$, with $k$ being an integer and $l$ as the fractional part. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

It is customary to accept an answer if it is helpful. Please feel free to leave comments on my answer if you think there are any concerns.

If $x=0,1$, there’s nothing to prove, so let’s assume that $x\ne 0,1$. The given “eventually cyclic” behaviour means there are positive integers $M,k$ such that, for all $m \ge M$, $a_{m+k} = a_m$. This implies that $b_m := x^{m+k} - x^m$ is an integer for all $m\ge M$. Note that $b_m = x^{m-M} b_M$ for all $m\ge M$. Using this relation for $m=M+1$, we find that $x$ is rational (because $x\ne 0,1 \implies b_M \ne 0$), so let $x=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Then, $b_m = (p/q)^{m-M} b_M\in \mathbb Z$ implies that $b_M$ is divisible by arbitrarily large powers of $q$, which is impossible unless $q=1$ (the case $b_M = 0$ is excluded because $x\ne 0,1$). Therefore, $x$ is an integer.
